# Blender 3+ version is freezing constantly on Macos

Tags: modeling, versions

I'm using Blender for a lot of years now and since version 3 on Macos I'm getting constant freezings. Blender not responding, etc. Nothing much in the scene, even with simple cubes.

The only way to recover is to close blender and open again.

I happened to notice it freezes more when I'm actively using Ctrl+Z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was autosaving feature. You just need to turn it off. Manual saving works fine!

Comment: would it explain the freezing with Blender 3? Turning off autosaving should not be the solution though, I hope they will fix the problem

Comment: @moonboots problem dissapeared after I reinstalled whole macOS and installed fresh new version of Blender. I did not encounter problems after that. I think this problem is obsolete and they fixed it